# integer value not changing from function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvAsy.png)  Hi I am trying to get my click Power variable to double when function Upgrade is called however nothing is happening. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it `this.clickPower *= 2` (in the `Upgrade` function), with the equals in order to alter the value of the variable.

Comment: That's not the only issue. `clickPower` is a variable not a property of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set an equal. The upgrade return is going nowhere, because upgrade is used as an onClick callback.

Using `this.clickPower` is not a good idea. If you want to initialize it in the render function, because it is not a props, state or ref.

React is rerendering following props and state, so you should set your `clickPower` in a state if you want to use it properly.

You should better initialize upgrade out of the render function.

```js
// Not event callback mode : 
let clickPower = 1;

function upgrade(value) => {
   return value * 2;
}

clickPower = upgrade(clickPower);

// As callback but not in a React App
this.clickPower = 1;

function upgrade(e) => {
   this.clickPower *= 2;
}

// Good way
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { clickPower: 1 };
}

function upgrade(e) => {
   this.setState({ clickPower: this.state.clickPower * 2});
}
```

Plus :

```js
const { money, setMoney } = this.props;
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much, this was a great help :)